# centos cpu usage is very high, but I cannot find the process

Tags: linux, performance, centos, cpu-usage, centos7

I use the command top/htop to find the process, but i failed.
The cpu pecentage of every process is only 0.x%.
How can i find the exactly one process that cause the hight cpu usage?

Comment: command 'top' may help.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing is showing up as using CPU time, it could be something like disk access time causing the perception of slow CPU.

You mentioned htop.
In htop, try hitting F2 for setup, arrow down in the 'Setup' column to select 'Columns'.  Arrow to the right twice, and arrow down until you see 'IO_RATE' selected.  Press 'enter' to add it to the active columns list.

You can adjust it's position by highlighting it and pressing F7 and F8 to move it up or down respectively.

With IO_RATE added to your output, look for processes that appear to be constantly writing to disk.

Along the same vein, check the process states as well, and look for "D" (uninterruptible sleep, usually I/O).  [PS info reference](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ups.htm)